# Prove that $ n \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 \log k} \to0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am wondering if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n  \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 \log k} = 0$, and how I would go about proving the result if the limit is correct. I thought of using an integral to approximate the sum but do not know how to integrate $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2 \log x}$ either.

Background:
I'm trying to prove the following question from Durrett:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be identically and independently distributed such that $P(X_i = (-1)^k k) = \frac{C}{k^2 \log k}$ for $k \geq 2$ where $C$ is chosen to make the sum of the probabilities = 1. Show that $E|X_i| = \infty$ but there is a finite constant $\mu$ so that $\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mu$ in probability.

I have been able to prove that $E|X_i|=\infty$ and am hoping to solve the latter part by applying a lemma that if $x P(|X_i|>x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, then $\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu_n \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: $$n  \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 \log k}\leqslant\frac{n}{\log n}  \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\leqslant\frac{n}{\log n}  \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{n}{\log n}  \frac{1}{n-1}\leqslant\frac{2}{\log n}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_n^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2\log x}<\frac{1}{\log n}\int_n^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n\log n}$$